# Figure out the missing card

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

[image: COLORED CARDS WITH NUMBERS ON THEM.]

Look at the colored cards with numbers on them (image above). Can you figure out the color of and what's on the mystery card?

*The correct answer may not be what it seems at first...*

---

**HINT #1:**

> [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking)

**HINT #2:**

> Read the answer that I posted below this puzzle.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

> Look at the colored cards with numbers on them (image above). Can you figure out the color of and what's on the mystery card?

The answer is:

> The mystery card is **purple with a question mark on it.** This puzzle was designed to trip you up into thinking that the numbers on and colors of the cards follow a specific pattern/rule, but they're actually randomly generated. If you read the question carefully, *"Can you figure out the color of and what's on the mystery card?",* you'll realize that the solution is right in front of you.

Comment: This feels like https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: @Duh-Wayne-101,  it seems you asked a question, you yourself have answered it and even voted for your answer. :€)

Comment: Unfortunately for you, the misdirection is not only xkcd 169, but just wrong. The title says the figure out the missing card, and your answer shows that the title is a lie. That's not good. You cannot make a statement and say it is a lie for the sake of the answer. Furthermore, "Look at the colored cards with numbers on them", which is not true if the "?" is the literal symbol and not an implied number. If you are going to xkcd 169, do it right.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the other answer, seems like

> it's a taking things too literally party! Whoo!

So my answer would be:

> "Can you figure out the color of and what's on the mystery card?" => "Nope!"

Answer (score 4):

It's

> Grey with an 8 on it.

Explanation:

> If you're going to break the assumption that the question mark represents a number we're supposed to find, then I'm going to break the assumption that the "missing card" is actually represented in the image. If the card is "missing", it can't be the purple one, since the purple one is clearly present. I randomly chose a color and number, so the card I found fits in perfectly with other random cards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the clues,

> Colour- pink and '?' appear on the mystery card